# what is the equivalence of do monad in haskell

Tags: haskell

Say I have a function that calls other functions

```
fun1 x1 x2 = do
    a <- fun2 x1
    b <- fun3 x2
    return [a:b]
```

Is there any short representation for this function.

Comment: Do you really mean `[a:b]` or rather `[a,b]`? Or maybe `a:b`?

Comment: do is no monad, but syntactic sugar for functions operating on monads. I don't understand what's your question, could you clarify what you want to achieve and where you have problems.

Comment: `fun1 x1 x2 = (\a b -> [a:b]) <$> fun2 x1 <*> fun3 x2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand the do notation using the bind operator

```
fun2 x1 >>= \a -> fun3 x2 >>= \b -> return [a:b]
```

but this seems way less clear to me....

(as per @sepp2k's comment, note that the example will compile, but might not have the type you intended it to)